# How to solve the conflict dependency of Rx Java version 1 and 2 in Android

Tags: android

I have only used `RxJava2`,but Why conflict occurred with `RxJava1.1.5`

I am getting below exception:

```
  Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformResourcesWithMergeJavaResForDebug'.
  com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: com.android.builder.packaging.DuplicateFileException: Duplicate files copied in APK META-INF/rxjava.properties
  File1: /home/panhao/Android/myGradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/io.reactivex.rxjava2/rxjava/2.0.0-RC5/ecd92d1147d9858c23087801a3bc2f323d481472/rxjava-2.0.0-RC5.jar
  File2: /home/panhao/Android/myGradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/io.reactivex/rxjava/1.1.5/ece7b5d0870e66d8226dab6dcf47a2b12afff061/rxjava-1.1.5.jar
```

Answer (score 0):

Issue occurs due to two main reason as mentioned below.

1. Your might forgot to remove older version dependency from gradle or libs for the Rxjava
2. Or your project might contain some library module which might have dependency to the older or newer version of same library used by you in your project.

> you need to add resolution strategy as mentioned below in your
>   projects build.gradle file. this will force your project to use
>   mentioned version of library

```
android{
.......
  configurations.all {
      resolutionStrategy {
        force 'io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxandroid:2.0.1'
      }
  }
}
```